# Problemas com a instalação do Android Studio no Linux Fedora

Tags: java, android, linux

Há alguns dias tento instalar o editor Android Studio no linux Fedora e não consigo.

Pesquisei em alguns tutoriais, sites, google e não consegui encontrar uma solução para lidar com o erro abaixo apresentado:

> ERROR: Cannot start Android Studio\nNo JDK found.
>   Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

Alguma ideia de como solucionar este problema?

Comment: Qual o conteúdo das variáveis de ambiente STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME e JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abra o arquivo `studio.sh` e adicione o `JAVA_HOME` diretamente nele

UNAME=`which uname`

GREP=`which egrep`

GREP_OPTIONS=`""`

CUT=`which cut`

READLINK=`which readlink`

MKTEMP=`which mktemp`

RM=`which rm`

CAT=`which cat`

TR=`which tr`

JAVA_HOME=`/usr/java/latest`

Answer (score 3):

Para uma avaliação completa do teu problema, eis algumas coisas que precisas verificar para garantir que tens o que é preciso:

<sup>Instruções para Fedora Linux</sup>

1. Verificar se tens o pacote `jdk` instalado:

   ```
   rpm -qa | grep jdk
   ```
2. Se não estiver instalado, terás que proceder à instalação:

   - Faz o download do pacote adequado para o teu sistema a partir do [site da Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
   - Muda para `root`

     ```
     sudo -i
     ## ou ##
     su -
     ```
   - Instala o pacote o qual fizeste download

     ```
     ## JDK 32-bit ##
     rpm -Uvh /caminho/para/binario/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm

     ## JDK 64-bit ##
     rpm -Uvh /caminho/para/binario/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm

     ## JRE 32-bit ##
     rpm -Uvh /caminho/para/binario/jre-7u51-linux-i586.rpm

     ## JRE 64-bit ##
     rpm -Uvh /caminho/para/binario/jre-7u51-linux-x64.rpm
     ```
3. Verifica a instalação atual:

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   Deve dar algo parecido com:

   > java version "1.7.0_51"
   >   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51)
   >   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1, mixed mode)
4. Verifica qual o compilador:

   ```
    javac -version
   ```

   Deve dar algo parecido com:

   > javac 1.7.0_51
5. Adiciona `JAVA_HOME` à variável de ambiente:

   O mais comum é editar o ficheiro `.bashrc` na tua diretoria de utilizador:

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```

   E adicionar ao final do mesmo:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-<versão>
   ```

   <sup>Nota: Após isto pode ser necessário voltar a realizar o login para que as alterações sejam todas assumidas.</sup>

---

#### Resposta original

O teu problema costuma na sua forma mais comum ser uma questão de permissões.

Experimenta mudar as permissões da pasta:

```
chown -R root:root /caminho/para/android-studio
```

<sup>Crédito da solução para [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633218/352449) do SOEN dada por @nikodroid.</sup>

Comment: Não consegui, tentei da forma que você colocou e nada!

Comment: Meteste o caminho correto para a pasta do android-studio? E já agora, definiste a variável de ambiente do JAVA? _assumindo que o instalaste :)_

Comment: Sim, coloquei sim e nada meu irmão.

Comment: @Faro Coloquei instruções mais detalhadas para que possas confirmar os vários detalhes.

Comment: Cara, o java tá aparecendo mais... depois que eu coloquei os alternatives e o eclipse já não quer abrir, o que faço...

Answer (score 1):

Cara eu quebrei a cabeça mas consegui no win7 que estava com o mesmo problema,a solução foi
computador>propriedade_do_sistema>variáveis_de_ambiente>
Aí tive que criar uma nova em **Novo=>
 nome da variável: JAVA_HOME
 valor da variável: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11**
Esse "valor da variável" é o mesmo da variável "PATH" encontrada no mesma tela de variáveis só é colocar em editar e copiar esse campo. espero que em fim resolva

Comment: A pergunta é como fazer isso em Linux, não no Windows :/

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte:

1) Instale o JDK, Download [Aqui](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

2) Veja o directório da instalação. Para isso abra a consola e escreva o seguinte comando:

```
rpm -q -filesbypkg jdk
```

No meu caso foi `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11/`.

3) Abra o ficheiro **`studio.sh`** e adicione a linha **`JAVA_HOME`**

```
UNAME=which uname
GREP=which egrep
GREP_OPTIONS=""
CUT=which cut
READLINK=which readlink
MKTEMP=which mktemp
RM=which rm
CAT=which cat
TR=which tr
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/(seu directório, no meu caso jdk1.8.0_11)
```

4) Guarde o ficheiro. Feito!